# How to switch between text/headings with textarea with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML code that I want to add inline-editable box to. I want to be able to edit the content clicked. Right now the text are replaced with textarea containing the text value. But I'm not able to type in new values in the textarea.

Any ideas on why I cant edit the contents of the textarea?

```js
$("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p").click(function() {
  var element = $(this);

  $(element).after().html("<textarea class='form-control'>" + $.trim($(element).text()) + "</textarea>");

  $("textarea").mouseout(function() {
    element.html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a h2</h2>
<p>Some text here</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set custom `data-*` property to check the element is in editing state or not otherwise on each click event it would generate textarea repeatedly.

```js
$("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p").click(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  if (!element.data('editing')) {
    element.data('editing', true);
    $(element).html("<textarea class='form-control'>" + $.trim($(element).text()) + "</textarea>");

    $("textarea").mouseout(function() {
      element.html($(this).val());
      element.data('editing', false);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a h2</h2>
<p>Some text here</p>
```

**FYI :** In your code `after()` method doesn't have anything do which is useless actually.

---

Also which is not a good practice to put textarea inside the `h1` tag so completely replace it with the textarea which also avoid the problem in your code.

```js
$(document).on('click', "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p", function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var $text = $("<textarea class='form-control'>" + $.trim($element.text()) + "</textarea>");
  $element.replaceWith($text);
  $text.mouseout(function() {
    $element.text(this.value);
    $(this).replaceWith($element);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>This is a h2</h2>
<p>Some text here</p>
```

---

I think it's better to use HTML5 [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute.

```html
<h2 contenteditable="true">This is a h2</h2>
<p  contenteditable="true">Some text here</p>
```

Comment: Looks to be working, is it possible to add the style of element into the textarea as well? like the h2 are added to the textarea.

Comment: @sdfgg45 :  check the second snippet

Comment: Thats what i'm looking for :)